# Deployment of ARM: Authorization failed for template resource 'sql

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I try to deply SQL Server Logical server with PS and ARM. I can succesfully create logical server at portal with contributor rights, but cannot figure out what is wrong here.

I have here PowerShell ISE on Windows.

ARM template is copy and paste from https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-sql-logical-server/

```
//CODE
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $subscription

#ARM Deployment
$templateFile = "C:\Azure\SQLServer\azuredeploy.json"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -Name SQLDeployment `
  -ResourceGroupName my-rg `
  -TemplateFile $templateFile
```

ERROR:
    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 17.35.18 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The 
   template deployment failed with error: 'Authorization failed for template resource 'sql
    vasvtmcp42o3wko/Microsoft.Authorization/11fd61df-2336-5b96-9b45-ffc7160df111' of type 
    'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments'. The client 'john.smith@mycompany.
com' with object id '1115f3de-834b-4d28-a48f-ecaad01e3111' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope '/subscriptions/1111111
11111111111111/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sqlvasvtmcp42o3wko/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/11111df
-2336-5b96-9b45-ffc7160df168'.'.

Comment: Any update this issue? Could you let me know if it works or not?

Answer (score 2):

> I can succesfully create logical server at portal with contributor rights, but cannot figure out what is wrong here.

Because [the template you used](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-sql-logical-server/) will enable the `Advanced data security` for you, this will create a storage account and service principal for your sql server, then assign the service principal to the storage account as a `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role automatically.

[image]

To do this operation, your user account need to be the `Owner` or `User Access Administrator` in the resource group or subscription. Or you can also create a [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) which has `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` in its `actions`, then the role will also be able to do that.

So in conclusion, you have two options to fix the issue.

1.Navigate to the Resource group or Subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> add your user account as a role mentioned above e.g. `Owner`, then it will work fine. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal#grant-access).

2.When you deploy the template, specify the `enableADS` with `false` in the `azuredeploy.parameters.json` file. Then it will not enable the `Advanced data security` for you, and you will be able to create the sql server with the `Contributor` via the template.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serverName": {
            "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
        },
        "administratorLogin": {
            "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "value": "GEN-PASSWORD"
        },
        "enableADS": {
            "value": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The error clearly states the account that is being used for the action doesn't have the proper role assignment to perform the action.

`the client 'john.smith@mycompany. com' with object id '1115f3de-834b-4d28-a48f-ecaad01e3111' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope '/subscriptions/1111111 11111111111111`

This means your next step should be validating what role assignment is assigned to that user, and then checking that the role does have the permission to perform `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`

Comment: I have contributor right to resource group. That is not enough to execute ARM? I can create SQL Server in portal, but ARM requires more?

Comment: Where to go in Azure portal and what is permission level required? How come I cannot create resource with contributor rights? Reader permission level is less than contributor? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview

Comment: That is a different question than the initial question. I've already answered the question by telling you that you indeed do not have the permissions to perform the request as it states in the error. As far as the specific action you have to have access to  - You need `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`

Comment: Here is another resource you can use to get an understanding of your issue and how you might be able to get access to the particular action you need to have to perform the task.

[Azure Resource Manager resource provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations)

Comment: Also I see you don't typically flag questions as answered when they have been. Please do the needful if my answer helped you. Thanks and good luck!