# Deploying ARM with Azure DevOps - not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write'

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

What I need to do to able to grant correct permission?

I see doc here but don't know what I need to do at Azure Portal. I have currently contributor rights.
I can create any resource from portal, but this ARM deployment fails
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations

I have here PowerShell ISE on Windows.

ARM template is copy and paste from https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-sql-logical-server/

//CODE
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -Subscription $subscription

## ARM Deployment

$templateFile = "C:\Azure\SQLServer\azuredeploy.json"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `-Name SQLDeployment`
-ResourceGroupName my-rg `
-TemplateFile $templateFile
ERROR: New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 17.35.18 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplateDeployment; Message=The template deployment failed with error: 'Authorization failed for template resource 'sql vasvtmcp42o3wko/Microsoft.Authorization/11fd61df-2336-5b96-9b45-ffc7160df111' of type 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments'. The client 'john.smith@mycompany. com' with object id '1115f3de-834b-4d28-a48f-ecaad01e3111' does not have permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope '/subscriptions/1111111 11111111111111/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sqlvasvtmcp42o3wko/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/11111df -2336-5b96-9b45-ffc7160df168'.'.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question in Stackoverflow, I answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61118284/9455659), you could delete the new one.

Comment: How are you deploying this?  Contributor will not be enough. Even owner may not potentially be enough as Azure access is different then Azure Active Directory access since you are trying to write to Azure AD to grant the permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deployment of ARM: Authorization failed for template resource 'sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103487/deployment-of-arm-authorization-failed-for-template-resource-sql)